# Map two lists to parent class and nested class

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I have two lists, list of Accounts and list of Transactions that represent below model. Let's assume they look like this:

```
List<Response.Account> accounts;
List<Response.Transaction> transactions;
```

And the model:

```
public class Response
    {
        public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; } = new List<Account>();

        public class Account
        {
            public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
            public long AvailableCredit { get; set; }
            public double Balance { get; set; }
            public long? CertainDate { get; set; }
            public string CredentialsId { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }
            public bool Closed { get; set; }
            public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; } = new List<Transaction>();            
        }

        public class Transaction
        {
            public string AccountId { get; set; }
            public long Amount { get; set; }
            public string CategoryId { get; set; }
            public string CredentialsId { get; set; }
            public long Date { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string FormattedDescription { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public long Inserted { get; set; }
            public long LastModified { get; set; }
            public long OriginalAmount { get; set; }
            public long OriginalDate { get; set; }
            public string OriginalDescription { get; set; }
            public long Timestamp { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

To each Account class in Response class I want to assign a list of transactions by mapping ***Id from Account class*** and ***AccountId from Transaction class***. I am aware I could do that by iterating over Accounts or Transactions and checking if both ids are equal and then assign to proper collection but that would cause nested iterations and I am not sure about its efficiency. What should I do? The only contraints in this model are those two lists in the beggining.

Comment: Unless the lists are huge iterating is likely to be quicker (KISS applies). Otherwise build a `IDictionary<int, Account>` and then iterate through the transactions adding them to the correct account.

Comment: " I am aware I could do that by iterating over Accounts or Transactions and checking if both ids are equal" Exactly what you should do. When in doubts about performance: **measure** and see if you *even have* performance-problems. Quite often you´re just hunting for a few nano-seconds that won´t hurt much.

Comment: Linq has a Join method you could perhaps give a try?  Instead of you doing the iterating, Linq will take care of it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Comment: @HimBromBeere I know where are you coming from ("run your horses", "preliminary optimization is an evil" etc.), but there is nothing wrong of having [performance culture](http://joeduffyblog.com/2016/04/10/performance-culture/). Some data structures/algorithms are known to perform better specific operations. In this particular case the LINQ `GroupJoin`. Following your point, LINQ  shouldn't provide `Join` and `GroupJoin` operators - iterate with  `Select` / `SelectMany`, apply `Where` / `Any` etc. operators and you are done. You can, but it's... just not "right".